# Audit Revoke Operations

Tags: database, oracle

How can **`REVOKE`** operations on a table be audited in Oracle?  Grants can be audited with...

```
AUDIT GRANT ON *schema.table*;
```

Both grants and revokes on system privileges and rolls can be audited with...

```
AUDIT SYSTEM GRANT;
```

Neither of these statements will audit object level revokes.  My database is 10g.  I am interested in auditing revokes done by SYS, but that is not my primary concern so the answer need not work for the SYS user.

*A trigger could catch these, but I would prefer to use the built in auditing, so if a trigger is the only way to do this, then vote up the "This can't be done" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Oracle Support all revokes can be audited by doing the following:

1. Set the parameter `audit_sys_operations` to `true`.
2. Set the parameter `audit_trail` to `db_extended`.
3. Run audit grant table;

This covers both GRANT and REVOKE privileges ON tables views and materialized views.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done.